# Emacs -nw mode key bindings conflict with unity

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-unity

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (unity). When using emacs in nw mode, some emacs key bindings fail to work. For example if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, instead of moving the current page backward, the "View" menu pops up. Even after I canceled the "Show Menubar" option, Alt+v still does not work. Did anybody know how could I resolve the key binding conflicts?

Comment: If this only happens in `-nw` then it's likely that your terminal (which ever one you're using) doesn't support some of the key combinations. That's a very common issue with running emacs without a graphical frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

1. Click on Edit
2. Click on Keyboard Shortcuts...
3. Uncheck "Enable menu access keys".

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your ubuntu key bindings with [Compizconfig application](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/). Amazing thing about it for me is you can search a particular key binding. Go to advanced search and check 'search values' check box. Then you can search for `<super>`.